# google spreadsheet conditional formatting on a column

Tags: google-sheets

I have a set of data range from A to G for instance, at column G, I would like to format the cell as following

if the value of G2 is between C2 and D2, then the background color is green.

if the value of G3 is between C3 and D3, then the background color is green.

and so on for the next 500 rows

How may I do it in the latest google spreadsheet please?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

In G2 select Conditional Formatting select custom formula and enter

```
=and(G2>C2,G2<D2).
```

Then select Apply to range and enter G2:G. It will work for all  column G .

Answer (score 0):

Since *format the cell* I assume only to apply to ColumnG. Please try selecting ColumnG and Format, Conditional formatting..., change G1: in start of `Apply to range` to G2: and for Format cells if... select Custom formula is and insert there:

```
=or(and(G2<C2;G2>D2);and(G2>C2;G2<D2))
```

select green fill and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Change `;` to `,` if required for your locale setting.

With text labels in Row1 it is usually simpler to select the entire column and write such a formula for Row1.